# Link positioning inside of div;

Tags: javascript, jquery

Okay below I have posted the script I'm using and the `#targetDiv`, Basically my problem is when I move the link that is currently contained within the `#targetDiv` outside of the div, The link no longer loads the page inside of the div, Is there a way I can move the link outside of the `#targetDiv` and still have it load the page contents inside of the div.

**Script**

```
$(function(){
    $('#targetDiv').on('click', 'a', function(e){
         e.preventDefault();// prevent browser from opening url
         $('#targetDiv').load(this.href);   
    });
});
```

**Div**

```
<div id="targetDiv" class="collapse">
<a href="/page.php">Load</a>
</div>
```

The problem I have is that I want the `load` link to be outside of the target div however when I move it outside of the div it loads the main page not the content within the `targetDiv`.

**What I'm trying to achieve;**

```
<a href="/page.php">Load</a>
<div id="targetDiv" class="collapse">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a class to any links you want to use to load content

```
<a class="content-link" href="/page.php">Load</a>
```

And modify event listener accordingly so it handles both types of links

```
    $(document).on('click', '.content-link, #targetDiv a',function(e){
         e.preventDefault();// prevent browser from opening url
         $('#targetDiv').load(this.href);   
    });
```

Comment: When user clicks button in OP, the button that loads the new content is overwritten by the new content. *I believe the OP desires the button moved outside that div to prevent this happening.*

Comment: this would be fine but I need  `$('#targetDiv').on('click', 'a', function(e){` to be the `#targetDiv` otherwise the links clicked inside the target div won't be loaded within the div.

Comment: @charlietfl thankyou, really appreciate it. Will mark as the answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
$(function(){
    $('#divLoad').click(function(e){
         e.preventDefault();// prevent browser from opening url
         $('#targetDiv').load(this.href);   
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<a id="divLoad" href="/page.php">Load</a>
   <div id="targetDiv" class="collapse">
</div>
```

You can also do this (more difficult to be precise):

```js
$(function(){
    var divLoad = $('#targetDiv').prev('a');
    //alert(divLoad.attr('href') );
  
    divLoad.click(function(e){
         e.preventDefault();// prevent browser from opening url
         $('#targetDiv').load(this.href);   
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<a id="divLoad" href="/page.php">Load</a>
   <div id="targetDiv" class="collapse">
</div>
```